# Using たい-form in qualifiers

Tags: syntax

By "qualifiers," I mean something like this:

> **昨日見た**映画
>
> The movie **that I saw yesterday**

I understand that you cannot use たい-form to talk about what other people want. So, can we use たい-form in qualifiers? For example, can we say something like "The dog that wants to eat"?

> 食べたい犬

Or would that just end up translating as "The dog that I want to eat"?

Alternatively, could we use たがる to say that we think the dog wants to eat?

> 食べたがっている犬

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This grammatical structure is usually called a [relative clause](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/14550/5010).

Both ～たい and ～たがる can modify a noun that follows, and they can optionally have a subject marked with が [or の](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12825/5010). For example you can say:

> - 私が食べたい料理　the dish I want to eat
> - 肉を食べたがっている犬　a dog who wants to eat meat
> - その犬が食べたがっている肉　the meat the dog wants to eat
> - 彼が見たい映画　the move he wants to watch

As you may know, there is an important difference between ～たい and ～たがる, which is described in detail [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23861/5010).

食べたい犬 without any context is an ambiguous and confusing expression, but can be easily taken as "the dog which I want to eat," because たい *usually* describes the speaker's own desire.