# Does「がる」conjugate?

Tags: grammar

It's an auxiliary verb, so I'm not sure whether or not it can conjugate.
For example, is it correct to end a sentence with「。。。が欲しがります」？
Also, if you, for example, wanted to say that someone wants to want something, would「[誰か]は[何か]が欲しがりたいです」work?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it can conjugate just like a normal godan verb.

- 欲しがらない
- 欲しがります (-ません, -ました, ...)
- 欲しがれば
- 欲しがれ
- 欲しがろう
  <sup>(This is rare as the "let's want" sense, but can be used as part of the [(よ)うと/(よ)うが construction](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%A8-%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BE%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C-you-to-mai-you-ga-mai/), e.g., 欲しがろうが欲しがるまいが与えられる "is given regardless of whether one wants it or not")</sup>

But it has many semantic restrictions, so please read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23861/5010) before using them.

When do you ever say "I want to want it" in English in the first place? 欲しがりたい may be usable in a very limited context where the way you show your desire to someone is important, but it's probably best to forget something tricky like this until you reach the near-native level.

Comment: Well, actually, in English, it is fairly common to say that one "want[s] to want" something. It's similar to saying that one "want[s] to like" something. It just means that one hopes that one's preferences will change.

For example, if one wants to have a healthier diet, then in order to make the process easier, one would "want to want" certain foods that are nutritious but don't have as rich or potent of a taste as the unhealthy ones.

Comment: @DeityofAutomation Oh, is that so? ○○を好きになりたい is a common phrase for that meaning. Note that you cannot use 欲しい in the sense of "to want to do something" in the first place.

Comment: Oh, I know. I appreciate the tip though. In the English version, as I understand it, we are describing the psychological state of "wanting" itself. If I want to describe what someone else wants (technically, "shows signs of wanting"), I was told that I had to use「がる」、so「がりたい」only made sense. Can I correctly use「好きになりたい」for others also?

Comment: @DeityofAutomation "She wants to like him" is 彼女は彼(のこと)を好きになりたがっている. 彼女は彼のことを好きになりたい is also fine if the condition described in [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23861/5010) is met. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you. 理解いたしました。

Comment: I wouldn't say 'want to want' is a common English phrase myself. I would understand it, but I'd never heard it before today, and if I were to express the snetiment I'd probably say 'I wish I wanted ~'