# Why can てもらいたい mean "someone else wants me to do something for them"?

Tags: grammar, giving-and-receiving

> 逢桜「元々、才華学園入学前に持ってあと３年だろうって言われてたんだ」
>
> 逢桜「野球を辞めた理由も怪我じゃなくて、この病気が原因だよ」
>
> 逢桜「徐々に体が動かなくなっていく難病で、最終的には呼吸も出来なくなって亡くなるんだって」
>
> 逢桜「**両親はね**、わたしに少しでも長く生きて欲しいから、クリエイターとしての**活動は止めてもらいたかった**」
>
> 逢桜「でも、無理をいってここまで伸ばしてもらってた」
>
> 逢桜「だけだ、去年の12月ごろに大きな発作があった」
>
> 逢桜「その時にさ両親に強く創作活動を辞めて欲しいと告げられたんだ」

I understand that the meaning of the bold part is that "My parents wanted me to quit the creator's activities". But usually てもらいたい means "I want someone else to do something for me", not "someone else wants me to do something for them". So why can てもらいたい be used like that in the quotation?

Comment: You have asked a similar question :) https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/92895/5010

Answer (score 4):

両親は(私に)クリエイター活動を止めてもらいたかった can naturally be used in this situation because her parents' desire is a *past known fact* that doesn't require any assumption of the speaker.   The speaker clearly and directly knew her parents wanted her to quit at this time point in the past.

In [Can たい and たがる be used for a 1st/2nd/3rd person's desire?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23860/5010)

> たい expresses a desire. た-がる literally expresses giving off the impression of having a desire. たい can be used if one does not need to assume that they know about a specific desire of a specific person, and たがる can be used if one is making assumptions on another person's wishes.
>
> ---
>
> たい, situations that do not involve making assumptions about a person's desires:
>
> - **it turned to be a fact** that another person did desire it

両親は(私に)クリエイター活動を止めてもらいたがっていた is also perfectly natural, though.

**EDIT**: Of course 両親は(私に)クリエイター活動を止めて欲しかった and 両親は(私に)クリエイター活動を止めて欲しがっていた are also perfectly correct in this context. She used もらう because she knew her quitting was a beneficial action to her parents even if it was undesirable to the speaker herself.

Comment: Your statements are correct, BUT I think you misread the example, the examples says 「たかった」 but not 「たがった」。In which it is just a past tense that is used to imply something that did NOT happen.

Comment: @ed9w2in6 What do you mean? No one in this page seems to have mentioned たがった in the first place.

Comment: Yes,,, you did?

Comment: @ed9w2in6 Oh if that's wthat you mean... Judging from the last part of the question, I think it's safe to assume that the questioner is asking about how to use たい properly for a third-person subject. This is a FAQ. And a good explanation naturally  involves how it's different from たがる. I believe OP understands how to use もらう.

Comment: I see, I don't have the same judgement as yours but thats a valid interpretation.  Come to think of it the question is quite ambiguous.  Literally, the question is asking on the reason for an expression's meaning, which is quite an absurd question, it just does.

Answer (score 1):

> usually てもらいたい means "I want someone else to do something for me"

> not "someone else wants me to do something for them"

Your understanding is correct :)

> So why can てもらいたい be used like that in the quotation?

You just have be a bit flexible and implement the above understanding to a "he said I said" situation.

Quoting your translation "I want someone else to do something for me", it goes like this:

From the parent's point of view, I (the parents) , wanted someone else (their kid) , to do something (stop doing creator stuff) , for me (the parent).

---

> **BLAH** はね、 **BLOOP**たかったの

This pattern is not uncommon when a feminine person is trying to explain another entity's intention of the past. It's used in drama, anime, manga etc. due to the dramatic effect it carries.

Adding a question mark to the end would make it a direct question (and a totally different meaning). Without the question mark, the sentence sounds incomplete, which is intentional. So, we typically add a trailing **...** to make up for the incompleteness, and then the female will follow up with another sentence to elaborate.

If I were to translate, it would be like:

> **BLAH** you see, wanted to **BLOOP**

But this translation alone won't convey the dramatic effect of its Japanese counterpart. It's one of those patterns you'll get used to by watching girls confess/justify her friend's past actions. Or even her own, by using her own name.

Eg.

Smart person *"Why is this answer so long? It deserves a down vote"*

My mother *"dungarian just wanted chino alpha to understand... (more to follow)"*

> **dungarianはね、 chino alphaに理解してほしかった (more to follow)**

Comment: Thank you. So do you think using 活動を止めてもらいたがっていた or 止めてもらいたいと思っていた would make more sense in this context?

Comment: Your two examples are very good replacements! But, it wouldn't necessarily "make **more** sense" because this specific pattern carries its own effect. I edited to explain further.

Comment: I don't think his understanding is correct without more clarification.  「もらいたい」 has no restriction on the point of view.

Answer (score 0):

てもらいたい means `The subject` wants to receive.

So the `subject` or `topic` of that phrase is `両親` and thus 両親 were the ones who "`wanted to receive` the favor of us quitting the creator lifestyle, because even if it's only a tiny increase they want us to live a long life."

もらう = subject of the sentence receives.

So in this case, keep a flexible mind about who the main focus / focal point of the sentence is.  The sentence can "orbit" around any one or any group or any thing so keep a flexible slot for the subject in mind.

`Subject は blank がもらいたい。`

`As for subject,` `wants to receive blank`.

In this specific instance,

`As for our parents,`

`they wanted to receive the favor of us...`

= `they wanted us to...`

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering about the answers to this question.  I have been looking for a definitive answer to how you say "someone wants someone else to do something。" So far, possibilities include て欲しいと思います and てもらいたい.  The first answer said you can use てもらいたかった because there is no doubt about they want her to do. The third answer said whenever the subject wants something done you use subject が ...てもらいたう. However, when someone outside of my group wants someone to do something for then, I don't think it is correct to use てもらいたい。I am new to Japanese and certainly I might be wrong, but I wonder if もらいたかった is acceptable in this case simply
because her parents are part of her in group.

Comment: Welcome to Japanese Stackexchange.  Your answer here unfortunately is NOT an answer.  Please consider turning it into a comment.

Comment: Actually, if you turn this into a question I can write up an answer for it ^_^.

Answer (score 0):

> But usually てもらいたい means "I want someone else to do something for me", not "someone else wants me to do something for them".

This is incorrect.  Let me explain this semantically.  「もらいたい」 has no restriction on the point of view.  It is just one way to express `...want to`.
The point of view is usually expressed through context.**

In your case, 「両親**は**（ね、）わたし**に**（少しでも長く生きて欲しいから、クリエイターとしての活動は止めて）もらいたかった。」
Here I used bracket to indicate optional sections that can be skipped if we focus on the expression of "A wants B to C".  To be more clear:

- A :: 両親
- B :: わたし
- C :: 少しでも長く生きて欲しいから、クリエイターとしての活動は止めて

In which in Japanese it takes the form of:

- JP :: A は B に (C...て) + もらいたい
- EN :: A wants B to C.

Meaning wise, A and B are agents and C is the purpose.

- A answers WHO, だれが？
- B answers TO WHOM, だれに？
- C answers HOW, どうしてほしい？

---

**
It is worth noting that in daily speech where we skipped the subjects and objects, saying 「〜たい」more often implies `I want to...` while 「〜ほしい」 is more nuanced towards `I want you to...`.  So you are not complete mistaken.

Again, context matters and remember there are no strict rules for meaning or grammar in any natural languages.  *I would recommend to **forget about the grammar but focus on the expression** itself for learning*.

Linguistics side track: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributionalism

If you insist, to know more about the grammar, you can refer to this similar question:
[https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/dative-subject-constructions-with-もらえませんか](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/86023/dative-subject-constructions-with-%E3%82%82%E3%82%89%E3%81%88%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%8B)