# for what てもらいたい use for in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, sentence

「すみません、ちょっと見**てもらいたい**ものがあるんですけど」

Comment: Related https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93215/45489

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can てもらいたい mean "someone else wants me to do something for them"?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/93215/why-can-%e3%81%a6%e3%82%82%e3%82%89%e3%81%84%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-mean-someone-else-wants-me-to-do-something-for-them)