# Meaning of 知りたい in the following TV program

Tags: meaning

Here is the URL to the webpage of a TV program. [https://news.ntv.co.jp/feature/知りたいッ！](https://news.ntv.co.jp/feature/%E7%9F%A5%E3%82%8A%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84%E3%83%83%EF%BC%81) If I understand it correctly, 「知りたいッ」is the name of the program. There is a brief explanation of the program on the webpage. It says 「いま知りたい、ニュースのポイントを詳しく解説。暮らしに役立つ情報も」, which again contains the phrase 知りたい.

My question is about the meaning of 知りたい here. Specifically, who is the subject of "want to know"? Logically it is the viewer. But that contradicts the rule that たい can only be used to express the wish of the speaker.

Answer (score 2):

> who is the subject of "want to know"?

The audience of the program, or "generic you", or "everyone".

> But that contradicts the rule that たい can only be used to express the wish of the speaker.

As for the description of the program, there is no such rule. See: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23861/5010

The title itself can be understood as what's said by someone. It's just "I wanna know it!" used as a title.