Does んだな carry a nuance of question_
A character is kissing is girlfriend and thinks this:

ちゅーしたいんだな

Does it mean "She wanted to kiss me, huh?" or is more akin to "I want to kiss her"

Strictly speaking, it depends on the context and which dialect the speaker uses. But 98% of the time, it's the former. な doesn't necessarily have to be translated, but it's like "huh?".
EDIT:
In this context, if he had said "ちゅーしたがってるんだな", it means something like "So she's been (intentionally) giving signs to me that she wanted to kiss me" or "So, her behavior so far means she wants to kiss me". On the other hand, "ちゅーしたいんだな" suggests that he became certain about her internal desire to kiss him, even though she hasn't explicitly shown it. Please read this great answer.

Why is it not using がる then?

@LionGate https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/23861/5010
